# How to fetch a single value from multivalue attribute in sql

Tags: sql

I have one table called student.Table has 4 column.

Student : Table

```
Id Name    RollNo  SubjectCode
1  Rani    B0101   1,3,5,7,12
2  Samidha B0102   1,2,4,6,12
```

I want to find out name of student whose has subjectcode 2.

Query:

```
select name from student where charindex('2',subjectcode) > 0
```

But problem occure when subjectcode contain 12.Because 12 contain 2.How to solve it?

Comment: On a related side note: why do you have CSV in one of your columns? Isn't it an option to normalize that data?

Comment: PS. I think the actual question you ask may in essence be a duplicate of [this one on splitting CSV in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/314824/419956)

Comment: It is already created table.I can not modified it........

Comment: You can create a view over the top of it though ;)

Comment: which database are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Your query doesn't work because it will match `12` as well as `2`.

You can fix this by appending the delimiters on either side:

```
select name
from student
where charindex(',2,', ','+subjectcode+',') > 0;
```

That said, you really need another table, which is the association of students and subjects.  This table, say `StudentSubjects` has two important columns:  `StudentId` and `SubjectCode`.  If you had such a table, this query would be quite easy using standard SQL constructs.

Answer (score 0):

Split the CSV value and use the `IN` clause, like this:

```
 select name from student where '2' IN Split(',', SubjectCode)
```

For `Split` use, for example, the function mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/314917/419956).